# Formatting month in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, expression, azure-data-factory

How do you format the date expression in ADFv2 so that you can get '1' for Jan and '10' for Oct?

I've tried using `formatDateTime(dataset().date, '%M')`, but I'm not sure this is the correct thing. I'm trying to set the folder paths for example 2019/1/1 and 2018/12/20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the formatting options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and the function reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

I don't think you need the %, the following should work.

```
formatDateTime(dataset().date, 'M')
```

Comment: Great, thank you. The formatting doc is really helpful as well, have been struggling to find one!